# Quickbooks Online Not Saving Invoices Correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, quickbooks-online

I am trying to create Quickbooks Online(QBO) Invoices.  I am able to create the invoice in QBO, however the Amounts and Balances are set to 0.00.  I have confirmed that the invoice(QBOInvoice) that I am passing to QBO contains the correct information, however, the invoice(resultInvoice) I receive in return does not have the prescribed Amounts and Balances.

Any guidance or suggestions?  Thanks.

```
                    Invoice QBOinvoice = new Invoice();
                QBOinvoice.DocNumber = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10);

                QBOinvoice.Deposit = new Decimal(0.00);
                QBOinvoice.DepositSpecified = true;
                QBOinvoice.AllowIPNPayment = false;
                QBOinvoice.AllowIPNPaymentSpecified = true;
                QBOinvoice.BillAddr = customer.BillAddr;
                QBOinvoice.ShipAddr = customer.ShipAddr;

                QBOinvoice.CustomerRef = new ReferenceType()
                {
                    name = customer.DisplayName,
                    Value = customer.Id
                };
                QBOinvoice.DueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
                QBOinvoice.DueDateSpecified = true;
                QBOinvoice.PrintStatus = PrintStatusEnum.NotSet;
                QBOinvoice.PrintStatusSpecified = true;
                QBOinvoice.EmailStatus = EmailStatusEnum.NotSet;
                QBOinvoice.EmailStatusSpecified = true;

                var serviceRecord = db.t_CleaningRecords.Where(p => p.ID == MOSESInvoice.ServiceRecordID).Single();
                QBOinvoice.ShipDate = serviceRecord.ServiceDate ?? DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900");  //  Used to address the fact that the DB column allows for nulls;

                QBOinvoice.ARAccountRef = new ReferenceType()
                {
                    type = Enum.GetName(typeof(objectNameEnumType), objectNameEnumType.Account),
                    name = "Account Receivable",
                    Value = "QB:37"
                };

                QBOinvoice.Balance = MOSESInvoice.InvoiceAmount;
                QBOinvoice.BalanceSpecified = true;
                QBOinvoice.TotalAmt = MOSESInvoice.InvoiceAmount;
                QBOinvoice.TotalAmtSpecified = true;

                // Create Sales Line Item
                Line invoiceline = new Line();

                invoiceline.Id = "1";
                //invoiceline.LineNum = "1";
                invoiceline.Description = servloc.StreetAddress.ToString() + " :: " + MOSESInvoice.ServiceDescription;
                //invoiceline.Description = servloc.StreetAddress.ToString() + " :: " + servdef.ServiceDefinitionName.ToString();  // This maps to Sales Definition Name & Street Address.
                invoiceline.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(MOSESInvoice.InvoiceAmount);
                invoiceline.AmountSpecified = true;
                invoiceline.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail;
                invoiceline.DetailTypeSpecified = true;

                SalesItemLineDetail slidetails = new SalesItemLineDetail();
                slidetails.ItemRef = new ReferenceType() { name = "B2C - Every 1 Week" };  // Product/Service column on Line Item Detail.  1 = Services.  2 = Hours.
                slidetails.ServiceDate = serviceRecord.ServiceDate ?? DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900");

                invoiceline.AnyIntuitObject = slidetails;
                QBOinvoice.Line = new Line[] { invoiceline };

                Invoice resultInvoice = serviceme.Add(QBOinvoice) as Invoice;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return QBOinvoice;
```

Comment: Post the actual XML or JSON you sent to QuickBooks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  I was passing a SalesItemLineDetail value that did not exist in my QBO company.  So fail on my part for not sending the correct value.  But...

The API simply and quietly changed the invoice balance and total amounts, then accepted the new invoice.

It seems to me that the QBO API should have blocked the action, issued a warning, or not overridden the invoice balance and total amount as provided.

I logged a support ticket with Intuit and provided this issue and resolution.